# Error when using mySQL Query. How to fix this?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to get the rows that fulfill the below query but I get this error

```
Select*
from table
where XAMid = 1033
and my_data between '01-Apr-10 12.00.00.00 AM' and '20-Jun-13 12.00.00.00.00 AM'
```

The error I get is : error data format picture ends before converting entire input string

What am I doing here?

Comment: That isn't a SQL error. Sounds like your business logic is reporting an error. Having said that, your dates are not in a comparable format and will not work.

Comment: Try using a standard format for the date:  `'2010-04-01'`, for instance.

Comment: but those aren't a valid date strings.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the date/times are in correct format? Could you try

```
'2010-04-01T12:00:00.000'
```

instead of

```
'01-Apr-10 12.00.00.00 AM'
```

and the same logic applied to the end date?

So, here is what I thought:

```
Select*
from table
where XAMid = 1033
and my_data between '2010-04-01T12:00:00.000' and '2013-06-20T12:00:00.000'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `to_date` function, because you are using a string, not a date.

The query should be something like that:

```
Select*
from table
where XAMid = 1033
and my_data between to_date('01-Apr-10 12.00.00.00 AM') and to_date('20-Jun-13 12.00.00.00.00 AM')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select*
from table
where XAMid = 1033
and my_data between to_date('01-Apr-10 12.00.00.00 AM','dd-MON-YY HH.MI.SS.FF AM') and to_date('20-Jun-13 12.00.00.00.00 AM','dd-MON-YY HH.MI.SS.FF AM')
```